# Tricky Median Question

Tags: python, algorithm

Given n points, choose a point in the given list such that the sum of distances to this point is minimum ,compared to all others.

Distance is measured in the following manner.

For a point (x,y) all 8 adjacent points have distance 1.

```
(x+1,y)(x+1,y+1),(x+1,y-1),(x,y+1),(x,y-1),(x-1,y)(x-1,y+1),(x-1,y-1)
```

**EDIT**

More clearer explanation.

A function foo is defined as

```
foo(point_a,point_b) = max(abs(point_a.x - point_b.x),abs(point_a.y - point_b.y))
```

Find a point x such that sum([foo(x,y) for y in list_of_points]) is minimum.

Example

**Input:**

```
12 -14
-3 3
-14 7
-14 -3
2 -12
-1 -6
```

**Output**

```
-1 -6
```

Eg:
Distance between (4,5) and 6,7) is 2.

This can be done in O(n^2) time, by checking the sum of each pair.
Is there any better algorithm to do it?

Comment: Just for reference: A clone of this question is posted on [Programming puzzles and Code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3441/tricky-median-question).

Comment: looks like variation on [smalles circle problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest_circle_problem), which is O(n)

Comment: This is a copy of a question on interviewstreet.com -- I'm not sure if the guys running it would like this here.

Comment: Btw this is not called **'median'**, it's called [**'Fermat point'**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point). And we want to find that point in the list closest to it.

Answer (score 5):

**Update**: it sometimes fails to find the optimum, I'll leave this here till I find the problem.

this is `O(n)`: nth is O(n) (expected, not worst), iterating over the list is O(n). If you need strict O() then pick the middle element with sorting but then it's going to be O(n*log(n)).

Note: it's easy to modifiy it to return all the optimal points.

```
import sys

def nth(sample, n):
    pivot = sample[0]
    below = [s for s in sample if s < pivot]
    above = [s for s in sample if s > pivot]
    i, j = len(below), len(sample)-len(above)
    if n < i:      return nth(below, n)
    elif n >= j:   return nth(above, n-j)
    else:          return pivot

def getbest(li):
    ''' li is a list of tuples (x,y) '''
    l = len(li)
    lix = [x[0] for x in li]
    liy = [x[1] for x in li]

    mid_x1 = nth(lix, l/2) if l%2==1 else nth(lix, l/2-1)
    mid_x2 = nth(lix, l/2)
    mid_y1 = nth(liy, l/2) if l%2==1 else nth(liy, l/2-1)
    mid_y2 = nth(liy, l/2)

    mindist = sys.maxint
    minp = None
    for p in li:
        dist = 0 if mid_x1 <= p[0] <= mid_x2 else min(abs(p[0]-mid_x1), abs(p[0]-mid_x2))
        dist += 0 if mid_y1 <= p[1] <= mid_y2 else min(abs(p[1]-mid_y1), abs(p[1]-mid_y2))
        if dist < mindist:
            minp, mindist = p, dist
    return minp
```

It's based on the solution of the one dimensional problem - for a list of numbers find a number for which the sum distance is the minimum.

The solution for this is the middle element of the (sorted) list or any number between the two middle elements (including these two elements) if there are an even number of elements in the list.

Update: my `nth` algorithm seems to be very slow, probably there is a better way to rewrite it, `sort` outperforms it with < 100000 elements, so if you do speed comparison, just add `sort(lix); sort(liy);` and

```
def nth(sample, n):
    return sample[n]
```

---

For anyone out there who wants to **test** his solution, here is what I use. Just run a loop, generate input and compare your solution with the output of bruteforce.

```
import random
def example(length):
    l = []
    for x in range(length):
        l.append((random.randint(-100, 100), random.randint(-100,100)))
    return l

def bruteforce(li):
    bestsum = sys.maxint
    bestp = None
    for p in li:
        sum = 0
        for p1 in li:
            sum += max(abs(p[0]-p1[0]), abs(p[1]-p1[1]))
        if sum < bestsum:
            bestp, bestsum = p, sum
    return bestp
```

Comment: how is nth O(n)?  is it expected to recurse a fixed number of times?

Comment: no, but the processed list shrinks exponentially. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Partition-based_general_selection_algorithm

Comment: cute, thanks.  i'm about to post a fixed "brain dead" version.  could you have a look at it again?

Comment: What's the point with `mid_x1 <= p[0] <= mid_x1`? Should be just `p[0] == mid_x1`. Plus can you further explain `getbest`? I don't understand what you are doing.

Comment: @Evpok: that was a typo. I'd rather fix it first, then explain. Works most of the time /= that still a "doesn't work" for me:) /

Comment: hi, your bruteforce function has an error - it should be max(dx, dy) not dx + dy.  i had completely missed the sum and am giving up.

Comment: @yi_H Since the metric considered is Dinf, shouldn't `dist` be the max of the x- and y-distances to the median set instead of their sum?

Comment: Found out why the test cases are failing? Is the algorithm used correct or heuristic ?

Comment: @Greyhound: To understand why this algorithm sometimes gives the wrong answer, consider the points (i+1, 0) for in range (20), and five points at (0,100) and five at (0,-100).  Now, this algorithm will use the median (7,0), when it should actually use the median (10,0).  The point is that the points at (0,+-100) should not be affecting the x direction.  This algorithm would always work had the Manhattan distance been used in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine a scheme better than O(n^2), at least in the common case.

Build a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) out of your input points.  For each node in the tree, compute the number and average position of the points within that node.  Then for each point, you can use the quadtree to compute its distance to all other points in less than O(n) time.  If you're computing the distance from a point p to a distant quadtree node v, and v doesn't overlap the 45 degree diagonals from p, then the total distance from p to all the points in v is easy to compute (for v which are more horizontally than vertically separated from p, it is just `v.num_points * |p.x - v.average.x|`, and similarly using y coordinates if v is predominately vertically seperated).  If v overlaps one of the 45 degree diagonals, recurse on its components.

That should beat O(n^2), at least when you can find a balanced quadtree to represent your points.